# SharePoint 2016 500 internal server error

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am facing a critical issue with SP2016. When I upload many documents to SP16 document library using rest api call after many attempts (succeeded) one of the documents is failing and throwing error 500 internal server error. i tried this [HOW TO MAKE SHAREPOINT 2016 NOT FAIL LONG RUNNING UPLOADS](https://www.vioreliftode.com/index.php/how-to-make-sharepoint-2016-not-fail-long-running-uploads-large-files/) but didn't work for me, any other suggestions?
my code is below.

```
public async Task<bool> Save(string requestUri, HttpContent content)
    {
        var credential = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
            username,
            password,
            domain);



        using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler() { Credentials = credential, UseProxy = false })
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();



                var mediaType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");



                mediaType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("odata", "nometadata"));



                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(mediaType);



                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-RequestDigest", await this.GetRequestDigest());
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("binaryStringRequestBody", "true");



                string postUrl = this.siteUrl.EndsWith("/") ? $"{this.siteUrl}{requestUri}" : $"{this.siteUrl}/{requestUri}";
                this.logger.LogDebug("Executing SharePointService.Save: PostUrl={0}.", postUrl);



                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(postUrl, content);



                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();



                this.logger.LogDebug("Executed SharePointService.Save: PostUrl={0}", postUrl);



                return true;
            }
        }
    }
```